# How to get last month's First day in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working on a Calender app and it's working fine when i navigate to next month as i am able to get the last day of the month and from where i am able to get the first day of coming month .but when i navigate to previous month i m not able to get the last month's first day.Is there any way to get first day of last month.

Comment: If you hardcode the days of the month, you can pretty easily count back based on the current date.

Comment: How do you store each day? NSDate?

Comment: Can you retrive  last month and last year in integer? If yes then i have solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works fine for me

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:currentDate];

components.month = components.month - 1;
components.day = 1;

NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

This also works if your current month is january. NSDateComponents will automatically decrement the year and set the month to december.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                   fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    components.day = 1;
    components.month = components.month - 1;

    NSDate *lastmonthDay1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents: components];


    NSLog(@"First day of last month====: %@", [lastmonthDay1 descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
```

Comment: i have updated  code try now. components.month - 1;,-1 jan .if -2 dec 2013 try now

Comment: components.month - 1; means current month to previous month if you want to go back month continues  need to update components.month = components.month - n; n=1,2,3.....

Comment: Why the double assignment? `a = a = a - 1;` just doesn't seem right.

Comment: have you solved your problem or not use of this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below....

```
     NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[comp setDay:1];
[comp setMonth:CurrentMonth];//previous month
[comp setYear:currentYear];
NSDate *firstDayOfMonthDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
NSCalendar *cal1=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps1 = [cal1 components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:firstDayOfMonthDate];
// 1 for mon 8 for sun
int startWithDay=[comps1 weekday]==1?8:[comps1 weekday];
//1 for monday 
// 2 for tuesday and so on....
```

Let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: YourCurrentMonth can be any month.It is upon your logic.If you are  calling previous and next method for months then you can pass months(in integer)as YourCurrentMonth .

Comment: I was just confused by the unfavorable naming of the variable.