# How to get NSDate start of previous month?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I suppose that I ask duplicate question, but I can not find solution for me. I need to get 1st day of the previous month. As I understand I have to get calendar from today, subtract 1 month and set day to be 1st. After that I have to convert to date. Unfortunately I get last day of previous month.

I use following code:

```
NSDate *maxDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *calendarCurr = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendarCurr components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:maxDate];
[components setMonth:-1];
components.day = 1;

NSDate *minDate = [calendarCurr dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"%@", minDate);
```

**EDIT:**

Yes, it is duplicate, but answers in that question does not help me. I still get 30/09/2014 (when today is 17/11/2014) instead of 01/10/2014. I suppose that my problem is time of todays date.

Comment: that may be due to problem of time zone!!

Comment: An innocent question - Why you want first day. Actually we all know that every month's start date is 1. Unless it is more deep/complex requirement you need. Just get previous month.

Comment: Possible Duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873257/how-to-get-last-months-first-day-in-ios)

Comment: I suppose that this is duplicate, but I can not find it in Google. May be I don't search well. 10x, for links.

Comment: 10x, @Saurabh Prajapati. I think that this is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Here a new approach:

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatterYear = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatterYear setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSDateFormatter *formatterMonth = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatterMonth setDateFormat:@"MM"];
[formatterMonth setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSString *yearString = [formatterYear stringFromDate:today];
NSString *monthString = [formatterMonth stringFromDate:today];
NSInteger month,year;


if ([monthString integerValue] == 1) {
     year = [yearString integerValue] -1;
    month = 12;
} else
{
    year = [yearString integerValue];
    month = [monthString integerValue]-1;

}
NSDateFormatter *exitFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[exitFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[exitFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSString *stringDate;
if (month < 10) {
    stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld-0%ld-01",(long)year,(long)month];
} else {
    stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld-%ld-01",(long)year,(long)month];
}
NSDate *firstDatePreviousMonth = [exitFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

NSLog(@"View the date: %@",[firstDatePreviousMonth description]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong calculation.
Use this code to set Month component.

`[components setMonth:components.month -1];`

Comment: It is the same, I get 30/09/2014 when today is 17/11/2014. I need to get 01/10/2014.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSString *stringCurrentDate = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:currentDate];
int monthInt= [stringCurrentDate intValue];

[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:currentDate];
int yearInt = [dateString intValue];

monthInt-= 1;
if (monthInt== 0) {
    monthInt= 12;
    yearInt -=1;
}

dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-01-%@",[@(monthInt)stringValue],[@(yearInt)stringValue]];
NSLog(@"this is previous month first date : %@",dateString);
```

run it as it is, obviously first day of month will be 01, so this is static here. your can change accordingly. happy coding

Comment: not particularly for 01/01/2014 this date... it will return you last months first date, like now its 11th month.. it will return 10th month first date.

Comment: I mean, @Nitin, that in the way you did if you have to calculate for January, you will receive 01/12/**2014**. You switch only month, but not year.

Comment: @new2ios you can see updated answer, i have not tested this updated answer, but for sure it will work. if it does not. let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSDate *maxDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendarCurr = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendarCurr components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitTimeZone | NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:maxDate];

[components setMonth:components.month - 1];

[components setDay:1];

NSDate *minDate = [calendarCurr dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>%@", minDate.description);
```